# Using setState in fetch. Error: Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Complete Error Here

[image]

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: this.state.emailInput,
      password: this.state.passwordInput,
    }),
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data === 'Success!') {
        this.setState({ route: '/' }, () => {
        document.getElementById('sign-in-button').click();
        signIn();
      });
      }
    });
```

I'm 90% sure that the error occurs because I'm setState-ing when fetching from the server.

I'm using the 'route' state to dynamically set up my NavLink from React Router v4.

Comment: Can you share full component code once?

Comment: Definitely sign-in causing redirection.

Comment: your fetch method(API calls) needs to be in componentDidMount().

Comment: check scope of `this`. it points to the `then()` and not `React`

Answer (score 0):

If your function in render method, it will give that error. Move your fetch function a [lifecycle method](https://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/).

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
          email: this.state.emailInput,
          password: this.state.passwordInput,
        }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data === 'Success!') {
        this.setState({ route: '/' }, () => {
        document.getElementById('sign-in-button').click();
        signIn();
      });
      }
    });
}
```